# Description & Short description not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, product

We're using Magento v1.9 and if we change the Description and/or Short Description of a product, the new text does not show on the frontend.
So, these 2 fields are not updated properly.

Any help is most welcome!

Comment: refresh your caches to ensure you are seeing the latest product data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a multistore, make sure you are editing in the correct store scope:

[image]

If you are editing the default values, make sure that in the specific store view the "Use default value" option is checked:

[image: use default value]

If not, then changes made to the "default values" scope will be overridden by whatever is in the "Default Store View" scope.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and Re-Index data. That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Most properly, this might be a cache issue. clear all the cache specially clear the full page cache if you are using magento EE.